# Dropping values before date X for each column in DataFrame

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'A': [20, 0.5, 40, 45, 40, 35, 20, 25], 
                  'B' : [5, 10, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 8]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range(start = "2010Q1", periods = 8, freq = 'QS'))

               A   B
2010-01-01  20.0   5
2010-04-01   0.5  10
2010-07-01  40.0   6
2010-10-01  45.0   8
2011-01-01  40.0   9
2011-04-01  35.0   7
2011-07-01  20.0   5
2011-10-01  25.0   8
```

Also, assume I have the following series of dates:

```
D = d.idxmax()

A   2010-10-01
B   2010-04-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

What I'm trying to do, is to essentially "drop" the values in the DataFrame, d, that occur before the dates in the series D for each column

That is, what I'm looking for is:

```
               A     B
2010-01-01   NaN   NaN
2010-04-01   NaN  10.0
2010-07-01   NaN   6.0
2010-10-01  45.0   8.0
2011-01-01  40.0   9.0
2011-04-01  35.0   7.0
2011-07-01  20.0   5.0
2011-10-01  25.0   8.0
```

Notice that all the values in column A before 2010-10-01 are dropped and all the values in column B are dropped before 2010-04-01.

It's fairly simply to iterate through the columns to do this, but the DataFrame i'm working with is extremely large and this process takes a lot of time.

Is there a simpler way that does this in bulk, rather than column by column?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is the most elegant answer, but since there aren't any other answers yet, I figured I would offer a working solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

d = pd.DataFrame({'A': [20, 0.5, 40, 45, 40, 35, 20, 25], 
                  'B' : [5, 10, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 8]}, 
                   index = pd.date_range(start = "2010Q1", periods = 8, freq = 'QS'))

D = d.idxmax()


for column in D.index:
    d.loc[d.index < D[column], column] = np.nan
```

**Output:**

```
            A       B
2010-01-01  NaN     NaN
2010-04-01  NaN     10.0
2010-07-01  NaN     6.0
2010-10-01  45.0    8.0
2011-01-01  40.0    9.0
2011-04-01  35.0    7.0
2011-07-01  20.0    5.0
2011-10-01  25.0    8.0
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. The only issue is that I'm trying to avoid iterating through the columns of d. The actual dataframe I'm using is enormous and it's eating up a lot of time.

Comment: @measure I figured that might be the case. I'll see if I can think of a better solution.